# Send sink() output to multiple files - R

Tags: r, sink

Is it possible to send `sink()` output to multiple files?

I would like it to do the following:

```
sink("log1.txt", append=T)
sink("log2.txt")

print("output text")
```

and have the "output text" appear in both files.

Currently, it only appears to write to log2.txt.

Comment: `sink("log2.txt", split = TRUE)` already covers most of the output, but not all of it.